# Tableau performance

Tags: tableau-api

I've a problem with the dashboard in Tableau. In the dashboard there are many worksheets, and all the columns that are in the report are calculable. The problem is that dashboard is being formed for a very long time. The report contains approximately 2 million rows. And it is generated about 5 minutes. 
Tell me, what are the solutions in this case?
Maybe I can somehow adjust the page display and not all the records at once?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code sample in your post.

Comment: Are you using a data extract or a live connection? What is the data source? How many worksheets on the dashboard? What version of Tableau? Have you tried using the performance recorder to monitor where the bottle necks are?

Comment: I advise reading this article  https://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/designing-efficient-workbooks

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the calculation time, try to exclude data you don't need with a data source filter in tableau. You can also hide or delete unused calculated fields. Other things you can do is reduce sheets that are not used.

Here's a link: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/5-tips-make-your-dashboards-more-performant-48574

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow to reduce calculation time:

1. Extract the data and use Extract data and also keep option as extract instead of live.Also replace the data source using extract data.
2. Use "User Filter" to reduce calculation time so that tableau will display of particular user data only.

I hope this will work to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more idea to resolve this issue.

1)when you loan first time your dashboard put into Dashboard Action Filter

First Time load dashboard data exclude in your sheet.

Dashboard Menu->Action->add action->select sheet and exclude option.

2) Live to Extract data source and select radio button extract.

3)use user filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the other answers (use extract, dashboard action filter...) and I want to add one point:

- Drag every field used by any tablesheet on the dashboard on "Detail" of every tablesheet you are using on the Dashboard. Now Tableau loads all needed data while loading the first tablesheet and can use this data for the other sheets.

i.e. A dashboard contains three tablesheets (A, B, C) now you drag every field used by A on "Deatil" of B and C, every field used by B on "Deatil" of A and C, every field used by C on "Deatil" of B and A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are also having a similar issue with 150 million rows but I want to check if you are doing following steps. This may help you. This goes back to fundamentals of Tableau reporting.

1/ Try to make sure your data set is in star schema format. This will help a lot in report.

2/ Try to have tables and views in DB in such a way that same columns are used in Tableau. Any extra columns in tables adds to the performance issue.

3/Make sure indexing is done properly for all the fields that are joined.

4/ In my experience Dashboard adds extra performance lag. So make sure you try to get as much performance tuning on sheets as possible before even going to dashboard.

5/ If required try to use materialized views.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture performance metrics using performance recorder option in Tableau.
Check for the underlying DB tables and joins present on the data source layer.

Try using optimized sets and parameters as required and get rid of less relevant filters.

Try using data extracts with scheduled refresh with data source filter for limited business years data.